# Postgresql slow query performance

Tags: postgresql, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

One of the Postgres table that I am working on has more 300 million rows. I am trying to select rows from that table based on a column (status_code) having possible values as 'Complete', 'In_Progress', or 'New'.

Select query where clause:  status_code != 'Complete'. This query is running for more than 20 minutes. I am not sure if creating an index on this table on column 'status_code' will help or it will further degrade the performance.

Also I am thinking in this scenario if creating a partitioned table based on status_code will work better instead of an index.

I ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the Select query:

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select name_key
from role_player_name
where status_code != 'Complete'

Result:
Seq Scan on role_player_name  (cost=0.00..13696237.01 rows=238537921 width=34)

(actual time=0.096..348576.907 rows=239484245 loops=1)

Filter: ((status_code)::text <> 'COMPLETED'::text)

Planning Time: 0.792 ms

Execution Time: 358239.975 ms

Look forward for some suggestions.

Regards

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for the slow query and the ddl for the tables and indexes involved? (All in plain text)

Comment: Without the explain (analyze), we cannot figure out what is slowing the query. Please share the output of explain (analyze).

Comment: updated EXPLAIN ANALYZE result, thanks